# Why isn't my call to a value-returning function working?

Tags: c++, function

I've tried to make sure my function prototype and definitions are good. The compiler doesn't show me any errors with those. And I've looked up in my textbook to make sure I'm writing my function call properly, but it still doesn't work. What am I missing? (VERY new to programming here. Please be kind.)

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool noNegatives(int intArray[], int arraySize);

int main()
{
    int mainArrSize = 5;
    int mainArr[] = {7, 12, 4, 69, -2};
    bool funcResult;

    funcResult = noNegatives(mainArr, mainArrSize); //Here's the call that wont work 


    if (funcResult = true)
          {
          cout << "The array did not contain any negative"
              << " integers." << endl;
          }
      else
          cout << "The array contained negative integers." << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool noNegatives(int intArray[], int arraySize)
{
    bool result = false;
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
        {
            cin >> intArray[index];
                if (intArray[index] < 0)
                    return false;
        }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: `if (funcResult = true)` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Here is Compiler Explorer showing you the warning, in case you haven't enabled the warnings in your setup: https://godbolt.org/z/xhZzF-

Comment: Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions to understand exactly what went wrong and one possible way to automatically catch it.

Comment: Your `noNegatives` function sets `result` to false - and no other value anywhere. That's highly suspicious.

Comment: You have a typo in condition `if (funcResult = true)`. It should be `if (funcResult == true)` It works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/peStKX . GCC produces informative warning for that: https://godbolt.org/z/x8JNxE

Answer (score 2):

Actually the compiler does warn about this line.

```
if (funcResult = true)
```

Perhaps you meant to compare

```
if (funcResult == true)
```

Always compile with at least `-Wall`, and take any warnings you see seriously. In fact, treat them like errors. You can even enforce this by compiling with `-Werror`.

Comment: Addendum: Never ignore warnings. They are the compiler pointing out potential logic errors in your code. The code may be syntactically correct and compile, but the presence of warnings usually means the resulting program doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Enable warnings and do not ignore them.

Here, the important part of the warning was "note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison". (Note: this is the warning which Clang provides, other compilers will have different warning texts. All compilers will warn about this mistake.)

```
<source>:16:20: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (funcResult = true)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:16:20: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    if (funcResult = true)
                   ^
        (                )
<source>:16:20: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (funcResult = true)
                   ^
                   ==
1 warning generated.
```

### 2. Create and assign at the same time

This is your code:

```cpp
    bool funcResult;

    funcResult = noNegatives(mainArr, mainArrSize); //Here's the call that wont work 

    if (funcResult = true)
```

I would declare and initialize the variable at the same time. I would write it like this:

```cpp
    bool funcResult = noNegatives(mainArr, mainArrSize); //Here's the call that wont work 

    if (funcResult = true)
```

Because if I do this, I can also make the variable const! And then, the little mistake would not compile, which would tell us about the problem earlier.

```cpp
    const bool funcResult = noNegatives(mainArr, mainArrSize); //Here's the call that wont work 

    if (funcResult = true) // Now this line won't compile anymore
```

### 3. Use C++ containers not C-style arrays

The `(int intArray[], int arraySize)` signature is dangerous (memory unsafe!) and can be replaced by either a `std::vector<int>` (if the size is not fixed at compile-time), or by `std::array<int, 5>` (if the size is known at compile-time).

Here's how your code would look like, after making this change:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool noNegatives(std::vector<int> const &intArray) {
  bool result = false;

  for (int index = 0; index < intArray.size(); index++) {
    if (intArray[index] < 0)
      return false;
  }

  return result;
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<int> mainArr = {7, 12, 4, 69, -2};
  const bool funcResult =
      noNegatives(mainArr); // Here's the call that wont work

  if (funcResult == true) {
    std::cout << "The array did not contain any negative"
              << " integers.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "The array contained negative integers.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Minor changes there:
1. Do not use "using namespace std".
2. Moved the declaration and definition of `noNegatives` to the same place, just to make it a bit cleaner.
3. Do not use `std::endl`, prefer `\n` + `std::flush`. And in case the `std::flush` isn't needed, drop the flush.
4. If something is constant, just mark it as such. That's just a good habit. In this case, `mainArr` is constant.

### 4. Use modern C++ range-based for-loops

Instead of raw array access using indices, it is better to use a range-based loop. So we transform this code:

```cpp
  for (int index = 0; index < intArray.size(); index++) {
    if (intArray[index] < 0)
      return false;
  }
```

into this:

```cpp
  for (int value: intArray) {
    if (value < 0)
      return false;
  }
```

### 5. Optional: Use `std::all_of`

C++11 and later provides many great algorithms, so that you don't have to write your own. You are checking that a condition ("is Positive") holds for all elements in a container.

For this, [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) exists.

After including `<algorithm>`, we can make the `noNegatives` function be a single line:

```cpp
bool noNegatives(std::vector<int> const &intArray) {
  return std::all_of(array.begin(), array.end(), [](int x) { return x >= 0.; });
}
```

`[](int x) { return x >= 0.; }` is a [lambda function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019) and defines a function which takes an `int x` and then returns whether it is positive.

### 6. Optional: Get rid of `iostreams`

`std::cout` creates a lot of extra code when compiled. For fixed strings, you can use `puts("Hello\n");` from `#include <cstdio>`. A more generic solution is to use [`fmt`](https://fmt.dev/), but you'd have to install this on your system.

`std::cout << "The array contained negative integers.\n";` becomes
`puts("The array contained negative integers.\n");`.

### Final result:

https://godbolt.org/z/4FVyOw

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  const std::array<int, 5> mainArr  {7, 12, 4, 69, -2};
  const bool allPositive = std::all_of(mainArr.begin(), mainArr.end(), [](int x) { return x >= 0.; });

  if (allPositive) {
    puts("The array did not contain any negative integers.\n");
  } else {
    puts("The array contained negative integers.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note, I replaced the `vector<int>` with `std::array<int, 5>` because then the compiler can optimize this to nothing. Here's the generated Assembly code:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, offset .L.str.1
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "The array contained negative integers.\n"
```